# Redirection from port 80 to 3000 with Nginx to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, debian, raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to use Nginx and Nodejs in a server I'm doing in a Raspberry Pi 3 with Debian Jessie installed.
I've opened port 80 in my router and configure the raspberry to have an static IP. For that reason I'm tying to use Nginx to redirect the traffic from port 80 to 3000, where I'm running the Nodejs instance.
The first time I configured Nginx it worked but I had to reboot the raspberry and once I did it I don't know why but it stoped working. Now, when I introduce my public ip in the browser I always get the Nginx initial screen. I've tried several configurations. Some of them are:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  root /home/punzano/mydite/dist/;
  server_name mydite.dev;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

or

```
upstream localhost{
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
server{
  listen 80;
  root /home/punzano/mydite/dist/;
  server_name mydite.dev;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

I would like some help with this because I've tried almost each combination and no one of them have worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you see the nginx welcome page, your configuration files above are not being read. Also, the second configuration should not have `:3000` in the proxy_pass.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I supose that the configuration file is being read because, if I have a syntax error or something like that, when I reload the service an error is shown in the console. If you can provide an example it would be great.

Comment: My fault :S. Apart from the port in proxy_pass it was also because I had the default configuration file linked in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/. Removing this link and the port solved the problem. Thanks for your help @RichardSmith